# What is the IntelliJ shortcut to create a local variable?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

In Eclipse if you have a method:

```
String MyObject.getValue();
```

When using this you can go:

```
MyObject.getValue();
```

If you cursor is on the line and you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> you get a context menu to 'assign a new local variable', resulting in the following:

```
String value = MyObject.getValue();
```

Can you do this as easily in IntelliJ? I've search the net but without success.

Comment: ProTip if you don't remember a keyboard shortcut: Wherever you are in the code, if you hit [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [A] ([cmd] + [Shift] + [A] in Mac) it will show a list of actions by name, you can type the action you want to do (e.g. Variable) and execute it

Comment: In Eclipse, it's faster to do "Ctrl-2 l" (lower-case L).

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Yep! This is the [***Introduce Variable***](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html#Introduce_Variable) refactoring. By default, select some text, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (for Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). If the expression is incomplete or invalid, IntelliJ will still make a good guess about what you meant and try to fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was using CTRL+ALT+F but this didnt offer a 'local' option.

Comment: And,you can press Shift+Tab to choose variable type,IDEA will remember your choice for future.

Comment: Is there a possibility to declare the variable final via keyboard, without clicking on the popup?

Comment: I think once you specify that the variable should be final the first time, your selection is remembered in the future (in IntelliJ 14 at least).

Comment: @John Feminella:How do you make it 'final' without making usage of the mouse ? (Intellij IDEA 2017.2.1) ?

Comment: Alt +Shift + V on Linux

Comment: I always used to use alt+enter at the variable location, and arrow down to "introduce local variable" but that dialog stopped being available for me today. Does anyone know why that would be? Now I have to use ctrl+alt+V.

Comment: That's super handy!

Answer (score 58):

IntelliJ 13.1 introduced [Postfix completion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/).

With Postfix Completion you can introduce a local variable by typing:

```
MyObject.getValue().var
```

and pressing `ctrl + space` or `enter`.

It even works inside other statements. For example:

```
foo.someMethod(myObject.getValue().var);
```

Answer (score 14):

for mac users:
`alt + enter` at the position where you want to generate your variable

Comment: This is my go-to method. Is there a way you know of to default to a typed instance? I often have to alt + enter again and select "Add type annotation"